# Creating a toggleClass on same level div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to toggle a class "closed-arrow" on an existing div class called "open-arrow" when a same level div with a class name "toggle-box" is clicked.

Currently I have this working - but it will toggle on all divs with class name "open-arrow". I only want it to work on the div that is clicked.

View the example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6gZAY/

Here is the current code that toggles the class "closed-arrow", how do I modify the code change the clicked area?

```
$( 'div' ).next( '.open-arrow' ).toggleClass('closed-arrow');
```

Comment: Be aware IDs must be unique on document context, your HTML markup in jsFiddle is not valid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$(this)` to get a reference to the current clicked `.togglelink` anchor as well as using **[.siblings()](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/)** to target only the sibling `.open-arrow` div of clicked anchor, so you can do:

```
$(this).siblings( '.open-arrow' ).toggleClass('closed-arrow');
```

instead of:

```
$('div').next( '.open-arrow' ).toggleClass('closed-arrow');
```

Updated Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6gZAY/1/

---

According to your comment, you can use:

```
var closedArrow = $(this).siblings( '.closed-arrow' );
$('.closed-arrow').not(closedArrow).removeClass( 'closed-arrow' )
$(this).siblings( '.open-arrow' ).toggleClass('closed-arrow');
```

Updated Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6gZAY/3/

Comment: Thanks Felix. I did that and it worked.

I noticed though that when I click on a panel and then click on another panel the arrow state keeps the arrow ready for the close (even though it is closed). Any idea why? Do I need to reset somehow?

Comment: Again that does the job Felix!
Where would I start looking to add code that would allow me to scroll center vertically the panel to the window when on the click?

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
$(this).siblings( '.open-arrow' ).toggleClass('closed-arrow');
```

instead of

```
$('div').next( '.open-arrow' ).toggleClass('closed-arrow');
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6gZAY/2/)